# Use sed to Replace NULL Columns

Tags: sed, hive

I'm using hive command to export data from Hive, it outputs a plain text file, fields terminated by \t, and lines terminated by \n.

Say there are some NULL columns, also some 'NULL' characters within a value, like the following:

```
NULL    NULL    NULL
ABCD    ABCDNULLABCD    ABCD-NULL-ABCD
```

I use the sed command to replace NULL with \N (for loading into MySQL):

```
hive -f query.sql | sed 's/\bNULL\b/NULL/g' >data.txt
```

The result is:

```
\N  \N  \N
ABCD    ABCDNULLABCD    ABCD-\N-ABCD
```

So the problem is, for \b modifier, '-' also matches, and the NULL between '-' is replaced.

Any way to solve this?

Comment: `Awk` (for example) can handle this issue simpler because it splits fields in spaces. Or `perl` with look-aheads. Are you stuck with `sed`?

Comment: @Birei I choose the perl version, it's much faster than sed. Thanks~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First let's create a sample to include all possible corner cases:

```
$ cat >sample.txt
NULL    NULL    NULL
ABCD    ABCDNULLABCD    ABCD-NULL-ABCD
ABCDNULL    x   NULLABCD
^D
```

(the whitespaces there are tabs)

I think it's cleanest to use look-ahead and look-behind regular expressions for such purposes, for example using `perl`:

```
$ perl -pe 's/((?<=\t)|^)NULL($|(?=\t))/\\N/g' sample.txt
\N  \N  \N
ABCD    ABCDNULLABCD    ABCD-NULL-ABCD
ABCDNULL    x   NULLABCD
```

If you really prefer `sed`, you can use [@Birei](https://stackoverflow.com/users/773159/birei)'s solution, it gives the same output.

Comment: You can't use `\b` in the alternation of the looks-around because it would match the same strings than in the OP case.

Comment: @Birei crap, that was a typo, I copy pasted the fixed output, without the fixed perl. I fixed it now, thanks for pointing out!

Comment: Thanks, the perl version is much faster than sed.

Answer (score 2):

As I pointed out in the comment, I prefer other tools, but [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) can also solve it using loops. It repeats the substitution command until it fails:

```
sed ':a; s/\(^\|\t\)NULL\(\t\|$\)/\1\\N\2/; t a' infile
```

It yields:

```
\N      \N      \N
ABCD    ABCDNULLABCD    ABCD-NULL-ABCD
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention what version of `sed` you are using. The following will work on almost all variants:

```
sed 's_^NULL\t_\\N\t_;s_\tNULL$_\t\\N_;s_\tNULL\t_\t\\N\t_g'
```

This uses underscore `_` rather that the typical slash `/` just for clarity.

On some versions of `sed` (e.g. IIRC HPUX 10.20) you will need to replace `\t` with an actual tab character.